# ¿Como mover un item de una lista a un determinado contededor con jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui

tengo un listado de items (ul li) y 7 diferentes contenedores divs con un color diferente cada uno, lo que quisiera es poder arrastrar un item de la lista hacia un div, permitiendo mover ese item a los diferentes divs si es necesario... espero explicarme mejor con la imagen:
[image: items]

El código es algo como esto (también está en [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/v265q/))

```js
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        remove: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery y jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="demo">

    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

</div>
<!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: Hola joshdz. Bienvenido a Stackover en español. Esta comunidad tiene algunas peculiaridades que deberías conocer, por ejemplo, no es un foro de discusión y tampoco un sitio de recomendaciones u opiniones. ¿Ya intentaste hacer algo con el ejemplo que publicas? ¿Lo has modificado? ¿Tienes algún error? Sigue estas pautas para incluir un [ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) del código que te da problemas. El real, el tuyo, con el que tu estás trabajando para resolver tu problema. Si necesitas recomendaciones o ideas, busca en Google.

Comment: Creo que deberías explorar las interacciones Draggable y Droppable de JqueryUI, que son las que te van a dar la funcionalidad que buscas. Los elementos serían "Draggables" y los contenedores "Droppables". Tu ejemplo, de todos modos, va bastante bien encaminado. ¿Qué duda tienes exactamente?